# Adding Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN to apache2 debian 7

Tags: apache, debian

I need to add the following:

```
Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
```

Now when I add it as is and restart apache2, I get this error:

```
Syntax error on line 272 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
 failed!
```

I need this done as it is risking my sites from [Clickjacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking).

Answer (score 7):

Old question - but, the answer is:

```
sudo a2enmod headers
```

Then, restart Apache.

Comment: Don't understand why you don't have a million upvotes on this! Cheers.